# Cron Job Commands not working

Tags: cron

I am new to cron jobs and have set up one in Plesk to execute every minute however I am not sure if the command is correct due to it not working.

```
 curl http://www.yourdomain.com/twitter_cron.php
```

I am running on a Centos VPS - the problem is I am not sure if I need a specific root to curl.

Answer (score 0):

```
sgeorge-mn:~ sgeorge$ which curl
/usr/bin/curl
```

You need to use full path in `cron` for `curl`; otherwise you need to have proper `PATH` variable specified in crontab

So for example:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/curl http://www.yourdomain.com/twitter_cron.php
```

Comment: Thanks - getting closer - but it is just throwing the error '-: /usr/bin/curl: No such file or directory'. I am not sure where to find curl location at present - still looking

Comment: Use the command `which` to find to out your path to `curl` as I showed in my answer.

Comment: comes back as /usr/bin/curl but still comes back with the same error. :(

Comment: Can you include the error message which you are getting in your question.

Comment: '-: /usr/bin/curl: No such file or directory'. sent via cron daemon

Comment: are you sure, that you have `curl` command in your system. If you can run this `curl` manually from `command line`, this cron entry will also work.

Comment: It runs from the command line - no problems. Perhaps it is another bug in plesk :) Will look into this.